# Stack overflow en el siguiente programa

Tags: c#, funciones

veréis, tenemos un proyecto para clase en el que tenemos que trabajar con funciones y hay diversas funciones para cada utilidad del programa, convertir de binario a decimal, hexadecimal... etc. El caso es que las funciones hacen correctamente la conversión y tal, pero al llegar al mismo bucle que las hace, me tira stack overflow error, y no tengo mucha idea por qué, os dejo el código que tengo hecho hasta ahora, a ver si alguien me puede dar una orientación:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UF2PR2Solucio
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int opcio = 0;
            bool acabar = false;

            while (!acabar)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                opcio = menuPrincipal();
                switch (opcio)
                {
                    case 1:
                        decimalBinari();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        binariDecimal();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        decimalHexadecimal();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        HexadecimalDecimal();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        binariHexadecimal();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        hexadecimalBinari();
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        qualsevol();
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        ajuda();
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        acabar = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("\nEsperava un numero de l'u al 9");
                        break;
                }
                if (!acabar) espera();
            }
        }
        public static void decimalBinari()
        {
            String numero;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra un numero decimal: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(10, numero)) Console.WriteLine(Conversio(10, 2, numero));
            else Console.WriteLine("Esperava un numero decimal");
        }
        public static void binariDecimal()
        {
            String numero;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra un numero binari: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(2, numero)) Console.WriteLine(Conversio(2, 10, numero));
            else Console.WriteLine("Esperava un numero binari");
        }
        public static void HexadecimalDecimal()
        {
            String numero;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra un numero hexadecimal: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(16, numero)) Console.WriteLine(convertirABaseDeu(16, numero));
            else Console.WriteLine("Esperava un numero hexadecimal");
        }
        public static void decimalHexadecimal()
        {
            String numero;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra un numero decimal: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(10, numero)) Console.WriteLine(Conversio(10, 16, numero));
            else Console.WriteLine("Esperava un numero decimal");
        }


        public static void binariHexadecimal()
        {
            String numero;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra un numero decimal: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(10, numero)) Console.WriteLine(Conversio(2, 16, numero));
            else Console.WriteLine("Esperava un numero binari");
        }


        public static void hexadecimalBinari()
        {
            String numero;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra un numero decimal: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(10, numero)) Console.WriteLine(Conversio(16, 2, numero));
            else Console.WriteLine("Esperava un numero hexadecimal");
        }


        public static void qualsevol()
        {//menu 7
            String numero;
            int baseInicial, baseDesti;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra un numero: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Entra la base en que esta aquest nombre: ");
            baseInicial = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Entra la base a la que el vols convertir: ");
            baseDesti = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(baseInicial, numero)) Console.WriteLine(Conversio(baseInicial, baseDesti, numero));
            else Console.WriteLine("El nombre introduit no és de la base especificada");
        }
        public static String Conversio(int baseInicial, int baseDesti, String Numero)
        {
            String resultat;
            int resultatB10;
            //Primer convertim de base inicial a base 10
            resultatB10 = convertirABaseDeu(baseInicial, Numero);
            //Despres convertim de base 10 a base desti
            resultat = convertirDeBaseDeu(resultatB10, baseDesti);
            return "hola soc la funcio conversio";
        }
        public static String convertirDeBaseDeu(int numero, int baseDesti)
        {

            String resultat = Conversio(10, baseDesti, numero.ToString());

            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(10, numero.ToString())) Console.WriteLine(Conversio(10, baseDesti, numero.ToString()));
            else Console.WriteLine("Esperava un numero en base 10");

            return resultat;
        }
        public static int convertirABaseDeu(int baseNum, String numero)
        {
            int resultat = 0;
            int llargada;
            int digit;
            int potencia = 0;

            llargada = numero.Length;
            for (int x = llargada - 1; x >= 0; x--)
            {
                digit = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(numero[x]);
                if (digit == -1) digit = Convert.ToInt32(numero[x]) - 55;

                resultat = resultat + (digit * Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(baseNum, potencia)));
                potencia++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("el valor a en decimal es : " + resultat);
            return resultat;
        }

        public static Boolean esBase(int laBase, String numero)
        {
            bool resultat = true;

            foreach (char digit in numero)
            {
                if (!digitPertanyBase(digit, laBase))
                {
                    resultat = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return resultat;
        }
        public static Boolean digitPertanyBase(char digit, int baseNum)
        {
            bool trobat = false;
            char[] simbols = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
            int x = 0;
            do
            {
                if (digit == simbols[x]) trobat = true;
                x++;
            }
            while ((x < baseNum) && (!trobat));
            return trobat;
        }

        public static int menuPrincipal()
        {
            int opcio = 0;
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

            escriureMenu();
            cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (Char.IsNumber(cki.KeyChar))
                opcio = Int32.Parse(cki.KeyChar.ToString());
            else opcio = 0;

            return opcio;
        }
        public static void escriureMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Conversió de bases numèriques");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Decimal a binari");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Binari a decimal");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Decimal a hexadecimal");
            Console.WriteLine("4 - Hexadecimal a decimal");
            Console.WriteLine("5 - Binari a hexadecimal");
            Console.WriteLine("6 - Hexadecimal a binari");
            Console.WriteLine("7 - D'una base a qualsevol altra");
            Console.WriteLine("8 - Ajuda");
            Console.WriteLine("9 - Sortir");
        }
        public static void ajuda()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Si saps que són les bases numèriques, no et cal gaire ajuda");
            Console.WriteLine("Si tens alguna queixa, pots escriure-la i,quan premis ENTER serà enviada al nostres programadors");

        }



        public static void espera()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Prem ANY KEY per tornar al menu");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


}
```

Muchísimas gracias de antemano a todos! Mientras, voy a seguir revisando yo el código, a ver si encuentro lo que sea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los breakpoint y explorar el codigo paso a paso son tus mejores amigos en este caso.

En esta funcion lo que ocurre es que llamas el codigo:

```
convertirABaseDeu(baseInicial, Numero);
```

el cual salta hacia:

```
public static int convertirABaseDeu(int baseNum, String numero)
```

Al terminar esta funcion la funcion anterior resume su ejecucion y llega a:

```
resultat = convertirDeBaseDeu(resultatB10, baseDesti);
```

La cual ejecuta:

```
public static String convertirDeBaseDeu(int numero, int baseDesti)
        {

            String resultat = Conversio(10, baseDesti, numero.ToString());

            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(10, numero.ToString())) Console.WriteLine(Conversio(10, baseDesti, numero.ToString()));
            else Console.WriteLine("Esperava un numero en base 10");

            return resultat;
        }
```

Al llegar a la linea:

```
 String resultat = Conversio(10, baseDesti, numero.ToString());
```

Creas una nuevallamada hacia la funcion al volverla a llamar cuando esta aun no ha terminado en la ejecucion previa:

```
public static String Conversio(int baseInicial, int baseDesti, String Numero)
```

La cual te genera que estas funciones se esten llamando infinitamente en un ciclo del cual no puedes salir. En la pila de llamadas podemos ver el comportamiento de los saltos entre ambas  funciones mencionadas:

La pila de llamadas despues de 4 iteraciones:

[image: Pila de llamadas 4 recursiones]

La pila de llamadas despues de 6 iteraciones:

[image: Pila de llamadas 6 recursiones]

La funcion:

```
public static String Conversio(int baseInicial, int baseDesti, String Numero)
```

Sigue acumulandose en la pila de llamadas hasta que se desborda y te da el error de StackOverflow

**Nota:** Sospecho que a de haber otra funcion similar en los otros casos de conversion donde quedas atrapado en llamadas infinita entre dos funciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora pillo el porqué del error, pero aún así no veo mucho cómo solucionarlo... Puesto que ciertas funciones devuelven el resultado correcto, otras lo devuelven dos veces... Tendrías alguna indicación más a darme? Llevo ya todo el día revisando el código y cambiando cosas y sigue sin salir... Estoy desesperado :')   Por otro lado como dije antes, muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta tan extensa, entiendo mucho mejor el funcionamiento, pero sigo sin ver por dónde meter mano a esto...

Comment: Sugiero que cada base tenga su propia funcion de conversion en lugar de usar una funcion de conversion unica para todo asi solo ejecutas la conversion necesaria y no tienes que estar convirtiendo de una base a base 10 y luego a la base destino

Comment: Después de darle vueltas llegué a la misma conclusión, teniendo en cuenta varios fallos que encontré al ejecutar ciertas conversiones, eso haré, muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada espero que te haya sido de ayuda, Saludos